# INSERT mySQL DATE not functioning using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert, phpmyadmin

I created a new table using PHPMyAdmin and I am having problems with `DATE` insert using PHP.  Very simple code and table for troubleshooting.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset ($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
    require ("PHP/header.php");
    require ("PHP/leftmenub.php");
    require ("PHP/bodya.php");

//create variables from hidden POST DATA
    $customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
    $requestdate = date('Y-m-d');

    @ $db = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
    if (!$db)
    {
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
        echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    }

    mysql_select_db('kitorders');
    $query = "INSERT INTO ECLIPSE "."(requestdate,customerid)"." VALUES "."  ('$requestdate','$customerid')";
    if (!$query)
    {
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Error: Could not insert to database.  Please try again.';
        require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
        require ("PHP/footer.php");
        exit;
    }

    require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
    require ("PHP/footer.php");
}

else
{
    echo "Thank you $FirstName, unfortunately there was a problem submitting the form.";
    require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
    require ("PHP/footer.php");
}
?>
```

I essentially want to insert the date when the rest of the data is inserted.  I have removed the other items from the table and INSERT for troubleshooting purposes.  I don't get an error, it acts as the query was accepted, but the data does not get inserted.  If I remove the `DATE`, the other data gets inserted.  I have tried using `DATE(Y-m-d)`, and `(Y,m,d)` to define `$requestdate`, nothing works.  I am using PHPMyAdmin for the MySQL creation.  I have tried 3 different tables, creating `DATE` to no avail.  I will attempt to attach a snapshot of the PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: where are you executing that query?

Comment: there are countless problems with this posts, spelling, indending, what have you tried.. basically every item on the stack overflow ruleset is violated... 
btw: mysql_* functions are deprecated!

Comment: Forgive me for the violations.  I am brushing the dust off from 10 years ago.  Much has changed, my old code is very deppreciated and as I get the rust out I will update this.  I switched to TIMESTAMP and the problem went away.  Sorry for the late replies, I was not getting email notifications that I received responses.  I have new problems now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date should not be an issue.  Due to the fact that you want to insert a current date,  I suggest to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` which is useful in order to gather neutral time zone data,  say if your users are located worldwide,  you don't mess with local server times issues.
Second avoid the use of such an old, deprecated and unsafe statements,  use `PDO`, which protects you against a `SQL INJECTION` which is a serious thread.

```
$insert=$db->prepare("insert into yourtable values (?, ?);");
$insert->execute(array($customerid, $date));
```

Don't know your table design or `schema`,  but I suggest to insert a timestamp as a validation, security element,  at the end after all data has been inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse/help.  TIMESTAMP fixed the problem.  I have been away from PHP and MYSQL for 10 years.  All my code is dusty and broken, but its comfortable for me (for now).  I am brushing the dust off slowly.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was useful @user3204564, please select it as an answer,  this way the time spent in answering questions is awarded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset ($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{  
  require ("PHP/header.php");
  require ("PHP/leftmenub.php");
  require ("PHP/bodya.php");

 //create variables from hidden POST DATA
  $customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
  $requestdate = date('Y-m-d');

  @ $db = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
  if (!$db)
  {
    echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
  }

   mysql_select_db('kitorders');
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ECLIPSE "."(requestdate,customerid)"." VALUES "."        ('$requestdate','$customerid')");  
   if (!$query)
   {
    echo '<br>';
     echo 'Error: Could not insert to database.  Please try again.';
     require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
     require ("PHP/footer.php");
      exit;
   }

    require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
    require ("PHP/footer.php");
 }

else 
{
  echo "Thank you $FirstName, unfortunately there was a problem submitting the form.";
  require ("PHP/bodyb.php");
  require ("PHP/footer.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you Set The `Type` of Your Date Row To `TIMESTAMP` in `PHPMyAdmin`?Your Code seems to be correct.

Comment: Changed to TIMESTAMP and problem solved.  But when querying the date, I get the date, plus the time.  Im sure there is a way to strip the time and just show the date.  Thanks for the support.  Wish I would get email notifications when you guys responded.  Sorry for the slow response.